# How to add thread MVC pattern theView to avoid JFrame Freezes

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, model-view-controller

I want run my GUI with thread to avoid freezes issues , how to add thread to view ? or Do you have any general idea to avoid GUI freeze issues.

```
public class Vark {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Object Creation For the View 
        VarkView theView = new VarkView();
        // Object Creation For the Model
        VarkModel theModel = new VarkModel();
        //  Object Creation For the Controller  passing  theModel and theView
        VarkController theController = new VarkController(theView, theModel);
        theView.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be mutating the GUI from the application main thread and not from the EDT. This is in violation of Swing's threading policy and **will** result in unpredictable behaviour leading to bugs and (possibly) death.

Comment: What do you mean by EDT ?

Comment: Start from the [beginning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). Writing a Swing application without knowing about the EDT is like trying a write a book without knowing the alphabet!

Comment: ok you mean event dispatch thread http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

Comment: I have already GUI , I didn't know about the swing policies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid freeze use [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for long running tasks. Also read about [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer would be most of work do on GUI thread, and only time-intensive jobs put on the separate thread (read about creating new threads, Runnable interface, ThreadPoolExecutor and Callable interface).

Generally there are a lot of patterns how to work. For starters it could be Producer/Consumer pattern.

As always with threads do not forget to protect shared data (synchronize, Locks) or even better - avoid to share data between threads :)